# ¿Cómo hacer que un cursor personalizado interactue con los objetos?

Tags: javascript, html, mouse

Mi pregunta va de la mano con la siguiente [página](https://themads.agency/)

Quisiera saber como interactua el mouse canvas con los objetos, por ejemplo el menú, entiendo que el cursor es un canvas, pero el como el circulo mayor se queda fijo cuando esta encima de algo que puede interactual es lo que me causa dudas.
Espero haber sido claro en la pregunta, pues el como explicarlo me tiene confundido.

Comment: Hola! Termina el [tour] para que puedas ganar tu primera medalla :D Y revisa [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas

Comment: Al decir canvas, ¿te refieres a la [tag de html5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)?